# Отключение SSL Apache FreeBSD

Tags: apache, ssl, freebsd, apache-modules

Проблема в следующем, забыли пароли от сертификатов. Хотим отключить ssl, но не получается. Закомментил `LoadModule ssl_module` делаю `apachectl start` выдает:

```
/etc/rc.conf: linux-enable=YES: not found
/etc/rc.conf: linux-enable=YES: not found
Performing sanity check on apache22 configuration:
Syntax error on line 36 of /usr/local/etc/apache22/vhosts/foo:
Invalid command 'SSLOptions', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
```

Менял `SSLEngine off` в файле `/usr/local/etc/apache22/extra/httpd-ssl.conf` тоже не срабатывает. Кто-нибудь может пошагово сказать как убрать ssl и запустить apache.

Comment: Вы отключили поддержку SSL, но в конфигах остались другие директивы с настройками SSL. Т.к. SSL теперь у Вас не поддерживается, эти директивы перестали работать и дают ошибки. Вам надо найти и закомментировать всё, что относится к SSL. В процитированной Вами ошибке это директива `SSLOptions`

Comment: Да уже закомментировал  все. Но спасибо за отзыв!